# How to validate supplied value before executing query using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client?

Tags: development, client

I am trying to update or create new items into a SharePoint list. There are various types of fields to update. For example Date, Integer etc.

My function accepts data in the form of DataTable with headers that match SharePoint field internal names.

The issue I face is if the user supplies a Date field without any value, my ListItem updates up to that point and shows error.

The solution that I thought of was to identify the field type and validate it before updating the list item. Consequently, if the value supplied is invalid, I skip the field. Is there a better way to do this, like some internal SharePoint feature etc.? I am very new to SharePoint.

My C# code below.

```
//listData - the data table that user passes to the function.
//spList - the list that user wants to update.
//spListItem - item I am trying to update or create.

var spFields = spList.Fields;
clientContext.Load(spList);
clientContext.Load(spFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var listColumns = (from DataColumn column in listData.Columns select column.ColumnName).ToList();
var spFieldInternalNames = spFields.Select(spField => spField.InternalName).ToList();
var validListColumns = !listColumns.Except(spFieldInternalNames).Any();

if (validListColumns)
{
    //spFieldDetails - a list of custom class with following properties
    //internal Field Field { get; set; }
    //internal Guid? RelatedListGuid { get; set; } -- to get GUID of related list if the field is of type LookUp.

    foreach (var spFieldDetail in spFieldDetails)
    {

        //my plan
        //get fieldType
        //run a validation on the value fieldValue


        if (validValueForTheField)
        {
            var fieldName = spFieldDetail.Field.InternalName;
            spListItem[fieldName] = fieldValue;
            spListItem.Update();
        }

    }
    clientContext.Load(spListItem);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    // currently I get an error here if there is any invalid value. Also I can't pin point which field caused the issue.                   
}
```